# C# Looking for a sortable array that handles both ints and strings

Tags: c#

I'm not really sure if what i'm looking for actually exists, so maybe you guys can help out.

I have the below data:

```
Apples|3211|12
Markers|221|9
Turtle|1023123123|22
```

The first column is always a string, the second column and third column are ints.  However, what I want to do is be able to reference theses as strings or ints, and then be able to sort via the third column asc.  Any ideas?

Something like MyTable[i].Column[i] and in this case MyTable[1].Column[2] would produce 12 as a int (because it's ordered).

Comment: It's not clear why you're not using a custom type which describes all three properties appropriately...

Comment: I've never created a custom type.  I tried a DataTable but this probably isnt what I'm looking for.

Comment: Any time you write *any* code in C#, you've created a custom type. If you're not familiar with how to design classes, now is the time to learn - it's a *core* skill, and it's not worth trying to do any more "real" work until you've got the hang of it, at least the basics.

Comment: How do you plan to use the sorted table?

Comment: I agree with @JonSkeet rather make a class with 3 properties one string and 2 int and then use that to do sorting and whatever other requirements you have.

Comment: What I have now is all three of those feed into a List<string> and then split, that just seems wrong

Comment: @Mike: So you need to build a `List<YourType>` - each line you read, parse it into an instance of your new type, and add that to the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want type safety you will need to create a class that holds each record:

```
class Record
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int SomeValue { get; set; }
    int OrderNr { get; set; }
}
```

Afterwards store them in a generic List<>, then you can order them, as you like:

```
List<Record> items = // read them into a list of items;
List<Record> orderedList = items.OrderBy(i => i.OrderNr).ToList();
```

**UPDATE**
Since it was requested I customized the answer from JustinNiessner to fit to my example:

```
string data = // your data as string
List<Record> records = data
    .Split('|')
    .Select(item => new Record
    { 
        Name = item[0],
        SomeValue = int.Parse(item[1]),
        OrderNr = int.Parse(item[2])
    }).ToList();

List<Record> orderedRecords = records.OrderBy(r => r.OrderNr).ToList();
```

This can be optimized by using `var` and not executing `ToList()` on the list, but is done this way in order to keep it simple for you to understand the concepts better.

Comment: This seems strange to me.  Why do you have a properties called "Apples", "Markers", "Turtle"?  From the OP, surely those are data values, not property names.  I realize that the OP didn't specify what the ints were, but this answer still looks strange to me.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Already corrected that, actually put a smile on my face when I noticed it :)

Comment: List<Records> items= new List<ProxyRecords>();
How do i insert the item into Records.Name?

Comment: @Mike Updated the answer with some code from JustinNiessner's answer

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have your data stored in some sort of `IEnumerable<string>` type, you could try something like:

```
var sortedObjs = stringRows
    .Split('|')
    .Select(r => new 
        { 
            ColA = r[0],
            ColB = int.Parse(r[1]),
            ColC = int.Parse(r[2])
        })
    .OrderBy(r => r.ColC).ToList();

var specificVal = sortedObjs[1].ColC;
```

Answer (score 1):

This speaks to a larger problem in your design.  Using collections to hold a bunch of disparate types with the intent of organizing them into some sort of structure is fragile, error prone, and completely unnecessary.

Instead, create your own type to organize this information.

```
class MyType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Whatever { get; set; }
    public int AnotherProp { get; set; }
}
```

Now your data is logically grouped in a nice, tight, type safe package.

Answer (score 0):

Your original post didn't specify what the ints were, but since you wanted to select them either by the Descripton(?) or the Id(?) and then sort them by the third column perhaps something like this will work for you?

```
//Code tested in LinqPad
void Main()
{
    //Apples|3211|12
    //Markers|221|9
    //Turtle|1023123123|22

    //Create a list of items
    var items = new List<Item>
    {
        new Item { Description = "Apple", Id = 3211, Sequence = 12 },
        new Item { Description = "Markers", Id = 221, Sequence = 9 },
        new Item { Description = "Turtle", Id = 1023123123, Sequence = 22 }
    };


    //Get sorted list of Apple by Description
    var sortedByDescription = items.Where(i => i.Description == "Apple").OrderBy(i => i.Sequence);

    //Get sorted list of Turtle by Id
    var sortedById = items.Where(i => i.Id == 221).OrderBy(i => i.Sequence);

}

public class Item
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Sequence { get; set; }
}
```